# Transfear google sheet, with drop down menu to publish on Zendesk, Can I do it in python, or should I look into SQL or JSON

Tags: javascript, python, sql, json, google-sheets

Link to working model, cars_view is what I use, cars_raw is the data. open tools and the script is pretty simple , 191 lines of code for it to work, but it can only be used one at a time, now I need to publish a live working face on Zendesk for view

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z3ZMvTu6HQcqJydKhqspBmYTWEoGb0HrCzQfshEsiTI/edit?usp=sharing